# Why doesn't this property update in UI?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, key-value-observing

I have a simple app: A text box bound to `item.title`. This property is exposed as a `NSString`, but internally is a `NSMutableString`.

The problem: Changes to the `title` property are not reflected in the UI.

Here is the implementation of `item`:

```
@interface Item : NSObject
{
    NSMutableString *_title;
}

@property NSString *title;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation Item

-(void)mutateTitle
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [_title appendString:@"mutated"];// this does not work
    //_title = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"new instance"];// this works
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
}

-(NSString *)title
{
    NSLog(@"get title returning: %@", _title);
    return _title;
}
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    _title = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:title];
}

@end
```

When a button is pressed, we send `mutateTitle` to the item, which changes the title, and notifies KVO of the property change.

The UI does respond to the change, and when `title` is called, we return the correct string.

But the UI does not reflect the changes.

Note that if I un-comment the line where I assign a new instance to `_title`, the update happens fine.

Also, if `title` returns a *copy* of `_title`, it also works fine.

Why is this happening? Is there a way I can make this work as I want?

---

*edit: `title` is being assigned elsewhere in the code; it is not `nil`.

Comment: Its better to use `self.propertyName` for KVC.

Comment: I believe _property doesn't do KVC as self.property does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because if the mutable string mutates, but the property doesn't change (the pointer still points to the same object), then KVC will not consider it a real change. That is probably done for efficiency reasons (in case that `didChangeValueForKey:` is called but the string is the same, there's no need to update the UI).

I suggest to don't use a mutable string at all, it doesn't fit to your purpose. Just use a normal string, and instead of mutating it reassign it:

```
-(void)mutateTitle
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    _title= [_title stringByAppendingString: @"mutated"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
}
```